# Initialzed an array by remote data

Tags: android, arrays

I am learning android and try to develop a project. For the project purpose, I want to initialize an array by using remote data. Though I don't know, is it possible or not!

suppose, this is an array

```
String values[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

This array is initialized but I want to initialize it to use some data which is coming from a remote server. And the remote server data is JSON encoded.

Is it possible or not?

if possible so how can I do it?

if not possible so what should I do?

Comment: read json and initialize your array then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. The frist thing you need to do is provide a code in order to get data from your server. Here an example using POST:

```
private String sendRequest(String targetUrl) {

    //Here, you define how method you'll use. In this case, I'm using POST
    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(targetUrl);
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    //If you need, place here your TIMEOUT. 
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            <TIME TO OUT IN MILLIS>);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, <TIME TO OUT IN MILLIS>);

    //Define here your client in order to make requests to your servers
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    //If you're using POST method, may be you need to add parameters in your request where it'll be used by your server in order to return a response to you.
    List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("<PARAMETER'S NAME>", "<PARAMETER'S VALUES>"));
    //You may add multiple parameters here

    //Here starts your request
    try {
        //Define your entity
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
        entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        method.setEntity(entity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        //In case of any error
        Log.e("REQUEST_ERROR", "Something was wrong: " + e);
    }

    try {
        //The string wich will receive your result
        String result;
        //Send your request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);         
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            BasicManagedEntity entity = (BasicManagedEntity) response.getEntity();
            //Get the result
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        //Return your result in order to be processed
        return result;

    } catch(ConnectTimeoutException cte) {
        return null;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

After this, call this function by writing:

`String result = sendRequest(<URL HERE>);`

So now you're able to process your JSON data. By knowing that your response is a String type but in JSON format, you need to add this code to get a JSON type from your String:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj = new JSONObject(result);
```

I don't know how your JSON is formated, but I think you're getting it as a array in JSON, right?

In this case, your can do something like:

```
String[] array;
JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("<KEY_TO_LETTERS_ARRAY>");
int size = jArray.length();
if (size > 0) {
   array = new String[size];
   for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
      array[i] = new String(jArray.getString(i));
   }
}
```

It's important too, before work with your array, maked sure if it's null or not because in the last code, the array is initialized only if the size of your JSON array is greater than 0.

```
if(array != null) {
  //It's ok
} else {
  //Something wrong
}
```

So now, your array is initialized.

Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` instead,

```
// initialize ArrayList of Strings
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

// add data to your Array list
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
```

you can add as much data as you want to your `myArray` because `ArrayList` size are dynamic.

adding more data,

```
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
myArray.add(yourDatahere);
```

to print data from your ArrayList,

```
for (ArrayList<String> data : myArray){
        System.out.println(data);
}
```

to retrieve data from your desired position use `myArray.get(position)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

convert your json in to string then-

```
jsonString.replace("},{", " ,");
String values[] = jsonString.split(" ");
```

it will remove inner "},{" and you will have your final string like {"a","b","c"}
just play with this.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String readJSONFeed(String URL)throws JSONException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/json");
    JSONObject params=new JSONObject();
    params.put("latitude", 43.6014049);
    params.put("longitude",1.4478449);
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params.toString()));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String url=.......................;
    protected  void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return readJSONFeed(url);
        }catch (JSONException jsonException){
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            // code to parse the jsonObject and assign it to your array
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

This is a sample code I write to use Post Method to get some data from a web service.According to your json structure, you can add some code to parse the proper data from JSONObject. Of course, you can use an GET methods to get data and use some other parameters.I hope this will be help ful to you.
By the way, I use the AsyncTask class to download the data asynchronized.